# PyPy: Unable to install sasl package with pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pypy

When I try to install `sasl` with

```
pypy -m pip install sasl
```

I get the following error

```
Installing collected packages: sasl
  Running setup.py install for sasl ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/pypy -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-XAoOSL/sasl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-2v_K2z/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl
    copying sasl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl
    running egg_info
    writing sasl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to sasl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to sasl.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to sasl.egg-info/top_level.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'sasl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'sasl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying sasl/saslwrapper.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl
    copying sasl/saslwrapper.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl
    copying sasl/saslwrapper.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl
    running build_ext
    building 'sasl.saslwrapper' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl
    cc -O2 -fPIC -Wimplicit -Isasl -I/usr/lib64/pypy-5.0.1/include -c sasl/saslwrapper.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sasl/saslwrapper.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
    sasl/saslwrapper.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_convert_PyByteArray_string_to_py_std__in_string(const string&)’:
    sasl/saslwrapper.cpp:297:98: error: ‘PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize’ was not declared in this scope
     #define __Pyx_PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize(s, l) PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize((const char*)s, l)
                                                                                                      ^
    sasl/saslwrapper.cpp:2698:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘__Pyx_PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize’
       __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyByteArray_FromStringAndSize(__pyx_v_s.data(), __pyx_v_s.size()); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[1]; __pyx_lineno = 56; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                   ^
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/pypy -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-XAoOSL/sasl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-2v_K2z/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-XAoOSL/sasl/
```

I'm on Centos 7 (Linux 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64). Following packages are installed:  cyrus-sasl-devel, python-devel, openssl-devel, pypy-devel

```
> pypy --version
Python 2.7.10 (bbd45126bc691f669c4ebdfbd74456cd274c6b92, Jun 30 2016, 15:15:02) [PyPy 5.0.1 with GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]
```

Comment: it looks like given package [uses](https://github.com/cloudera/python-sasl/blob/master/setup.py#L17) C++ extension which I'm not sure is supported by *PyPy* (but I might be wrong), what happens if you install it to *CPython*?

Comment: You mean Cython? It's already installed (Centos package and pip package for python and for pypy)

Comment: I mean "traditional" Python with C implementation, not PyPy

Comment: "pip install sasl" without pypy is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function only began to be supported from PyPy 5.4. I would suggest you use PyPy 6.0 This are available on the PyPy project download page https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads

Comment: Thanks, it resolves the issue. I had to compile pypy 6 to make it work on my Centos version.